# Modify href property (in this JSFiddle ) to work with youtube videos in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, youtube, fancybox, fancybox-2

Since upgrading from Fancybox 1.3.4 to Fancybox 2.1.4 i haven't been able to get the correct `href` property to work with my youtube videos.

Please take a look at this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZWv3/) that I am trying to modify.

Simply, all I want to do is remove the trailing `&amp;autoplay=1` from the URL of each link and add it to the `href` property inside the script. When I attempt to do so, fancybox opens but the youtube video doesn't play and reports a general error.

Can someone help me to modify this code into a working version ?

Here is the html :

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo&amp;autoplay=1">open youtube video</a>

<br />

<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=071KqJu7WVo&amp;autoplay=1">open youtube video 2</a>
```

and the javascript:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*=youtube]').each(function () {
        // convert youtube swf href to embed for iframe
        var thisHref = this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'embed/').replace(new RegExp("&", "i"), '?');
        // bind fancybox to each anchor
        $(this).fancybox({
        "padding": 0,
        "type": 'iframe',
        // add trailing parameters to href (wmode)
        "href" : thisHref+"&amp;wmode=opaque"
        }); // fancybox
    }); // each
  }); // ready
})(jQuery);`
```

Thanks.

Comment: All you want to do is replace the trailing "autoplay=1"? Just add this to the end of your replacing line: `.replace("autoplay=1", "")` - I think this is it: http://jsfiddle.net/yZWv3/1/

Comment: And by the way, your fiddle worked fine for me, as is, but it played automatically

Comment: No. In my case i have about 8000 youtube trailers which dont have the trailing &amp;autoplay=1 attached to their html source. What I would like to do is have a working example which autoplays without &amp;autoplay=1 in the html but rather in the javascript. Thanks. @Ian

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/yZWv3/3/ It seems to work for me, but I still may be misunderstanding the point. Notice how the first link works even if it already some query string on it

Comment: Hi @Ian thanks for your help! My example is Video 2 which now works without the trailing &amp;autoplay=1. If i need it to work only for Video 2 (as i have no cases of Video 1) what code can i get rid of in the javascript? Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! So will the URL **always** end with `watch?v=071KqJu7WVo` then, and have no parameters after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of links without any trailing parameters :

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">open youtube video</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=071KqJu7WVo">open youtube video 2</a>
```

Use this code

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*=youtube]').each(function () {
        // convert youtube swf href to embed for iframe
        var thisHref = this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'embed/');
        // bind fancybox to each anchor
        $(this).fancybox({
            "padding": 0,
            "type": 'iframe',
            // add trailing parameters to href (wmode) AND autoplay    
            "href" : thisHref+"?wmode=opaque&amp;autoplay=1"
        }); // fancybox
    }); // each
  }); // ready
})(jQuery);
```

The issue you had with the previous example is that `wmode=opaque` was your **second** parameter so it needed a preceding `&amp;`

```
"href" : thisHref+"&amp;wmode=opaque"
```

but since you are removing all trailing parameters from the link, then `wmode=opaque` becomes the **first** parameter so it needs a preceding `?` instead

```
"href" : thisHref+"?wmode=opaque&amp;autoplay=1"
```

See new **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7rEtS/)**